# Embed an IE-only page for display in Chrome (or other browsers)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, iframe

Simple question, where to even start?

I'm currently facing an issue where I need to open a page inside of my own. The issue is that **the URL will only work in IE**. To open this page I have to run Parallels and open in Edge with compatibility mode, otherwise half the elements are missing and I get console errors such as:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hidPanel')
```

## Requirements

- this URL needs to open in a modern browser in a pop up over my current site
- I can use any means necessary to get this to work, any libraries, any CSS, anything.
- I have no access to the code from the IE only site
- I'm working with Symfony, PHP and Vue
- Everything has to run within Chrome (i.e. no opening IE from Chrome)

## Question

Is there any routes I can take to start looking at getting this to work? Most of this seems out of my hands as its handled by the browser, but maybe there's even some browser extensions that might allow this?

## What Have You Tried So Far?

- Exploring quirks. Quirks are definitely running, however the page will still only open in Edge with compatibility mode. Edge without compatibility mode will still not show the contents of the iframe.

**For the mods voting to close this due to "requiring focus"**

I don't know when this site started getting like this, but you guys LOVE to close a question. This question is not focussing on multiple problems - the problem is that I need to open a page built for IE in an iframe on other browsers. That is the only problem. I realise this is vague, and a difficult question, but its all the information I currently have.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve what you want in code side, you can only make change on the browser side.

In Edge you can use [IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode) to display the IE-only page. If you want to set the page opening in IE mode automatically, you can configure [IE mode policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies).

But in other modern browsers, they're not dual engine so I think you can only use some extensions. For example, you can use [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) extension in Chrome to view IE-only pages.